# Get list of all loaded types in FxCop

Tags: fxcop

In a custom FxCop rule how do you find all implementation of a given InterfaceNode?

If there is easy way, can I at least get a list of all loaded types to find it out myself?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I couldn't find any public helper that gives me all loaded assemblies and types, but there is an internal property Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InternalUtilities.LoadedAssemblies in the FxCopSdk.dll which can be used to list all loaded types. From there it is pretty intuitive to find implementations of an interface.